# Cloud Foundry SSH on Windows?

Tags: ssh, putty, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to connect via SSH to the running instance of a POC application running on our Dev CF installation. If I issue the `cf ssh` command then I'm unsuccessful:

```
C:\>cf ssh poc-app
SSHing to application poc-app, instance 0...
OK
SSH username is vcap
SSH IP Address is 10.92.240.14
SSH Port is 62330
SSH Identity is C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gocf420090498/identity

Command: ssh -i C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gocf420090498/identity -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o StrictHostKeychecking=no
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -p 62330 vcap@10.92.240.14
```

If I've renamed PuTTY's SCP client to ssh.exe it complains that it can't process the `-o` option.

If I "remove" the `-o` options then it fails saying that `Local to local copy not supported`. I surmise that this error is because it cannot find the identity token specified in the `-i` option because the slash/backslash is in Unix format rather than Windows (and on checking the file system, there's nothing at that location).

Editing to incorporate the comments below. We've also tried this using `putty -ssh` and also OpenSSH. The errors vary, but ultimately (when we replace `-p` with `-P` on the PuTTY command line, relate to the file specified in the `-i` option not having been created in the Windows file system.

```
Unable to use key file "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gocf832783378/identity" (unable to open file)
Using username "vcap".
vcap@10.92.240.14's password:
```

Is there a way to get this working on Windows? I realise that if I stand-up a Linux machine that would be an easy solution but that's not something we can easily do. Additionally some of our developers' machines don't have the VT-X option set in the BIOS so "virtualizing" the command somehow is "difficult".

Comment: "I've renamed PuTTY's SCP client to ssh.exe" I'm sorry, what? Why are you renaming `scp` to `ssh`? What are you expecting to accomplish here? It's still going to act like an scp program, and parse its command-line options as scp options.

Comment: That's a good point. Changing it so that it points at `putty -ssh` delivers an `unknown option "-p"`

Comment: @Kenster I don't think it's a PuTTY problem per se, I think the issue is the output from the `cf ssh` command. One of my colleagues has also tried this with OpenSSH and it prompts for a password (presumably for the vcap user that should have been encoded within the `-i` provided file, except that's not there).

Comment: @GrahamNicol `cf ssh` is not supported for Windows cells. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=windows

Comment: @aminjam Thanks, but it's not the cell itself that's on Windows (that's on Linux) but the client that we need to call into the cell from.

Comment: What cf CLI version are you running? Are you using the built-in ssh sub-command (i.e. not from a CLI plugin)? I can `cf ssh` fine from Windows with the latest version, and not seeing all those status messages like "SSHing to application (...)". The current cf CLI does not invoke an external ssh tool (did it ever?).

Comment: we're currently running version 6.11.3. I'll double check to see if there's anything "special" in our version and give 6.22 a shot. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Great, 6.22 works perfectly and resolves all the problems we saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ssh command was added to the cf CLI in version 6.13.0. Before that, there was a diego-ssh plugin for the CLI.
The output in your question (the status messages) does not match the output I see when I run the cf CLI built-in ssh command on my Windows machine. Hence my suggestion to try the latest cf CLI version (6.22.1 as we speak).